# What are the possible cases where a SQL Too many connections issue can occur while using HikariCP in Spring Boot and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

Facing this issue very frequently. Can anyone please please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HikariCP too many connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505536/hikaricp-too-many-connections)

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like your database complains that you hold too many connections open, consume even more but don't close them again.
2. If you have the default connection pool settings of Hikari (which you should have and not specify i.e. a poolSize of 1000), this problem should basically not happen.